# why It always returns circularprogressindicator

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

```
Widget buildForm() {

    return FutureBuilder(

        future: usernameCheck(context,this.username),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot)  {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) { // not loaded
            
            return  CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return ErrorWidget(context);
          }
          else  {
            bool valid = snapshot.hasData;
            Future<bool> valid1;
            return Container(
              width: 330,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              child: Form(
                key: _userNameformKey,
                child: TextFormField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    _userNameformKey.currentState.validate();
                    setState(() {
                       valid1=usernameCheck(context,_userNameController.toString());
                    });

                  },
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty || valid1==false) {
                      setState(() {
                        onNextButtonClick = null;
                      });
                    }
                    else {
                      setState(() {
                        onNextButtonClick=next();
                        this.username = value;
                        this.usernameinfo.addAll(widget.previousFields);
                        this.usernameinfo.add(value);

                      }
                      );

                      return null;
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  controller: _userNameController,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  autofocus: false,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: '@username',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
    );
  }

}

Future<bool> usernameCheck(BuildContext context,String username)

async {

  
  if(username!=null) {

  final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Consumers').where('Username', isEqualTo: username).get();

  //converts results to a list of documents
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.docs;

  //checks the length of the document to see if its
  //greater than 0 which means the username has already been taken

    if (documents.length > 0) {
      //print(username + ' is already taken choose  another name');
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) =>
        new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Taken'),
          content: Text(username + ' is already taken choose  another name'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                    .pop(); // dismisses only the dialog and returns nothing
              },
              child: new Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call

Comment: this might be a dumb question,is this because 'context' is a parameter of usernamecheck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the snapshop ConnectionState instead.

If(snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
return  CircularProgressIndicator();

Comment: with this I came across a new problem which s as soon as i enter a letter it moves on to the next screen, so it does not allow the user to complete, can you help me in fixing that?

Comment: Can you share your code after my addition

Comment: actually, I solved the above problem but right now there are issues in connecting to firestore